# which is right approach for state management in SDUI scenario with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

Im working on a SDUI (Server driven UI) using Flutter,

In Runtime I receive JSON data, which parsed into set of widgets and set of map variable
I want to bind some of the key value pair of new map state to UI, **State-fully** ( meaning UI repaints corresponding widget if variable changes). further Map values may get modified locally, or from the server. And also cant predict which map variables to be monitored by state management at the compile time (JSON data tells this in runtime).

Can someone suggest right State management plugin (Mobx, Provider, etc) suitable for this kind of SDUI scenario

Or is it possible to do this without state management plugin with just flutter? any example available for this?